# How to migrate R decision tree to Java

Tags: machine-learning, r, decision-trees, java

I have trained a conditional inference decision tree in R using library `party` with function `ctree` and saved the model in an `.Rda` file.

I need to migrate this model from R to Java so that I can utilise the tree to make predictions in a Java environment. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your decision tree model to the PMML format. In Java you could use JPMML to parse/read the model and predict.

Comment: At present the R ppml function does not support party::ctree conversion to PPML format, but this wrapper https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml does.